# REST API Security Issues

Tags: rest, security

I have an html5 webapp that fetches data using jquery from rest java api. I have two questions:

1. How can I encrypt data on server and decrypt it locally with different key for each user. Where can I store this key in client side? Does it needed, or it is just enough to secure the rest service call with some authentication method?
2. Is there any standard way to prevent other rest clients (except browsers) to hit this rest api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use HTTPS
2. Use authentication so you know who is hitting it - oauth, client certificates, session token - but there's nothing you can really do to prevent anything other than a browser accessing it. You could make it harder by rapidly recycling the authentication token using javascript (but this will break in horrible ways if the user opens more than one window).

Comment: In point1 I was refering in the case that the data come to client encrypted. So if you open firebug you will not see the data come from json, but the encrypted one. Then javascript will have to decrypt them. My problem is where can this key can be stored securely

Comment: It can't. If a browser can decrypt it, so can any other agent.